# Pygame won't render rect at mouse position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I wrote this simple code, to spawn a rect at the mouse position when the mouse button is clicked. But it wont render the rect for some reason. It prints "mouse" when clicked, but no rect!

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


WHITE = (255,255,255)

while True:

    pygame.init()

    DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0],pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1],20,20))
            print('mouse')

 

    pygame.display.update()
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: Create the display and do `pygame.init()` once before starting the game loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize pygame ([`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init)) and create the display surface ([`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)) before the application loop.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
WHITE = (255,255,255)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            run = False

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print('mouse')
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, WHITE, (*event.pos, 20, 20))
        
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

However, the typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

Redraw the scene is every frame. The event occurs just once when the mouse button is clicked. Add the mouse click positions to a list and draw the rectangles in the application loop, at the positions stored in the list:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
WHITE = (255,255,255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pos_list = []

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            run = False

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print('mouse')
            pos_list.append(event.pos)

    DISPLAY.fill(0)
    for pos in pos_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, WHITE, (*pos, 20, 20))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing. Thank you so much dude !

Answer (score 1):

You actually **do** render the rectangle! The problem is that you re-initialize the window so fast that you do not see it in your **while loop**

This code will work:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, WHITE, (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[
                             0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1], 20, 20))
            print('mouse')

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you initialize the window in the while loop.

You have to do it like this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


WHITE = (255,255,255)
pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0],pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1],20,20))
            print('mouse')

 

    pygame.display.update()
```